# How to add "Inv. recpt date" field to Payment tab in MIRO?

Tags: abap, sap-erp, dynpro, badi

Is there any chance to add field "Inv. recpt date" to Payment block in Miro tcode so that the user could select "Inv. recpt date" instead of "Baseline Date". Is there any BAdi or BAPI?

[image]

Comment: You can do whatever you want in SAP software because the source code is provided and SAP permits to maintain it. Consequently, adding a screen field is always possible. Generally speaking, some BAdIs can let you implement new screen fields, that's easy to check by viewing the screen details and checking if an empty subscreen area exists, that's probably reserved by a user exit, i.e. you can include your own screen. Concerning BAPI, I don't understand how it could be related to a screen modification.

Comment: Raises a few questions. INVFO-BLDAT is on the Basic Data Tab. INVFO is available across the tabs.  Suggest you double check the requirement. Exactly which field do they not have access to ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no direct and straightforward way to add fields to MIRO payment tab, you can only add to details one (check `LFDCB001` enhancement).

However you can change payment tab values on-the-fly to whatever you need via **MRM_PAYMENT_TERMS** BAdI. For changing baseline date in `PAYMENT_TERMS_SET` method put something like this:

```
DATA: h_drseg TYPE mmcr_drseg,
      h_reindat TYPE RBKP-REINDAT.

LOOP AT ti_drseg INTO h_drseg WHERE selkz = 'X'.
  SELECT SINGLE budat FROM ekbe INTO h_reindat WHERE
                ebeln = h_drseg-ebeln  AND
                ebelp = h_drseg-ebelp  AND
                lfbnr = h_drseg-lfbnr  AND
                lfgja = h_drseg-lfgja  AND
                lfpos = h_drseg-lfpos  AND
                vgabe = '2'.
     
  CHECK sy-subrc = 0.

  e_zfbdt = h_reindat.
  EXIT.
ENDLOOP.
```

Here `h_reindat` is an "Inv. recpt date" which is assigned to baseline date in runtime.

If you want anyway to make it visible in UI for manual entry, I recommend to stick to standard approach described here: [How to activate Invoice Receipt Date in document header for any company](https://blogs.sap.com/2020/06/16/how-to-activate-invoice-receipt-date-in-document-header-for-any-company/)

It will be put on the MIRO basic tab and then value is copied to baseline date on payment tab.

For your reference: [SAP Note 1156325](http://1156325%20-%20BAdIs%20in%20the%20Logistics%20Invoice%20Verification%20environment) - *BAdIs in the Logistics Invoice Verification environment*